# Estimating a smooth ROC curve

Tags: roc, smoothing, sensitivity-specificity

Is there any algorithm which I can use to smooth the ROC curve and maybe another algorithm to fix points which are below the reference (chance) line?

[image]

Comment: Smells like plot manipulation =) You can just use LOESS as the general smoothing algorithm.

Comment: @GermanDemidov Can you explain me how to calculate the new roc curve using this algorithm? Maybe a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rufibach in [arXiv:1103.1787](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1787) has, besides the description of a new smoothing method, a pretty good introduction with an overview of your options to smooth ROC curves. I suggest starting from there.

To "fix" the points below the diagonal you will need a more discriminative detector. You can't really fix bad data with statistics.